# Plugin PerfMon Jmeter

Tags: jmeter-plugins

where can I found examples with exhausted explanation of Jmeter PerfMon Metrics Collector and also meaning of metrics, like CPU, Memory, Disc IO. The main point is to find examples and explanation of the results and not the description of what it is. Would be nice if somebody could share some real examples from their practice.
Just for information, I've already googled and found different kind of information, but always very surface information. Jmeter off-site provides the following info, but it is not enough
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=PerfMon

For example, I don't know how to interpret the following resulted charts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etMTp.png)
Here are preconditions:Number of threads -1000, ramp-up period - 1 , Loop Count -1

Chart 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3iJt.png)
Here are preconditions:Number of threads -100, ramp-up period - 500 сек , Loop Count -infinite, duration - 47 minute

Answer (score 0):

1. The list of metrics can be found under [Supported Metrics](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#supported-metrics) chapter
2. If you click `...` button under right of "Metric parameter" input it will JMeter will display popup with more comprehensive information on what's going to be collected and what are the options:

   [image]
3. With regards to "real examples from their practice" - in the majority of cases the test results are under [NDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement)

The main idea is to enhance JMeter KPIs with metrics of the application server performance counters in order to correlate the increasing load with increasing resources consumption and ensure that the the system under test has enough headroom to operate (or state that it's slow due to i.e. the lack of RAM). You may find [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) a little bit more detailed, however you won't find full description of 75+ metrics with real life examples there, it's supposed to be your job to analyze PerfMon listener output, if you will have problems with interpreting the result just start another thread with less broad question like: "here is the chart, what does this spike might mean"?